# History.push works on BrowserRouter but not Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history

So I'm trying to use history.push('/path') in my components. My set up looks like this:

*App.js*

```js
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// History
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

function App() {
  return (  
      <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/' exact render={(props) => <Homepage />} />
              <Route path='/search' render={(props) => <SecondComponent />} />
            </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**SecondComponent.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const SecondComponent = ({ history  }) => {

    const myFunction = () => {
        history.push('/search');
    };

    return (
    <button onClick={() => myFunction}>stuff</button>
    );
}

export default withRouter(SecondComponent);
```

The problem is that when I click the button the URL changes but the component doesn't render. The thing is if I replace `Router` in app.js with `BrowserRouter` it works fine but I get a warning: `<BrowserRouter>` ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`.

Comment: Could you please post the versions of `react-router-dom` and `history` libraries in your package.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-router 5x is compatible with history 4x. Check the history version, and if higher than 4x, try downgrading to 4x version, and it should work fine with `Router`